# System out of memory with 7GB still free

Tags: windows-8, memory, out-of-memory

As seen in the screenshot below, I was playing a game when it stopped and popped "Out of Memory" window. However Task Manager clearly shows that there is still 7.6 GB of ram still available.

What could be the reason for that?

[image]

Comment: This message refers to virtual memory. Look at the committed and pool statistics that you have cut off your Task Manager Screen shot.

Comment: @DavidMarshall why would the machine use virtual memory if there is so my physical left?

Comment: Virtual memory is committed when a program allocates it. Physical memory is not needed until a program writes something into the virtual memory. If the total of memory committed gets near to the sum of physical memory and paging file size, you start to get the message you see. This is because Windows guarantees that a committed virtual memory allocation can always be backed by either physical memory or paging file even before it is written to.

Comment: _Everything_ is in virtual memory. A subset of virtual memory is in RAM. Another subset is on the HD or SSD. A final subset is defined ("committed") but not yet used - in which case it needs no actual storage anywhere. But the "commit limit" mechanism in Windows ensures that the space will be available should it eventually be used.